# How to display "user_first_name" instead of "user_id" on each post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to assign every new post to the `current_user` who is posting it.

I managed to display the `user_id` of the person who is posting at the top of the post but when I try to apply the process with `user_first_name` it just doesn't work. I am displaying each  `@post.user_id`. What do I need to do to display each post's `@post.user_first_name`?

This is Feed.controller:

```
before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :feed]

def feed      
  @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  @post = Post.new
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create 
   @post = Post.new(post_params) 
   @post.user_id = current_user.id

  if @post.save 
    redirect_to '/' 
  else 
    render 'new' 
  end 
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
```

This is CreatePost model:

```
def change
  create_table :posts do |t|
  t.text :content
  t.integer  "user.id"
    t.timestamps null: false
   end
 end
end
```

This is CreateUser model:

```
def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where do you think `user_first_name` is defined? If you had a `fist_name` column in the database, it would be `user.first_name`. So you should show your user model. By the way, is you're "CreatePost Model" really a single file? If so, it is incorrect. `belongs_to :user` will go in the `app/models/post.rb` while the `def change` part will go in the migration.

Comment: So am I looking to define @post.user.first_name ? I am adding the CreateUser Model, and I changed the belongs_to and has_many thanks to you.

Comment: Ok that was the problem ! belongs_to and has_many were in the wrong place ^^ It works now. thank you !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. They'll help you when asking future questions.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to assign every new post to the current_user who is posting it.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/<<

In your create method, you could do this like so

```
def create
  if current_user.posts << Post.new(post_params)
    redirect_to root_path #'/'
  else 
    render :new 
  end 
end
```

> What do I need to do to display each post's @post.user_first_name

The best way to do this, would be to open up your post model in `app/models/post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :first_name, to: :user, prefix: true
end

@post.user_first_name
```

> I am displaying each @post.user_id

The reason you are able to do this is because `user_id` is a column on the `post` table, and thus is an instance method on `Post` class. but `user_first_name` is not an instance method on the `Post` class, it is on the `User` class. You can use delegation to create this method you are trying to use.